# Command to fetch 2nd line of xml file and rename the file with fetched name

Tags: xml, bash, command-line

I have an xml file names media.xml and it consist of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<table name="advisoryTable"/>
  <row>
      <field name="book">maths</field>
      <field name="book">science</field>
      <field name="book">eng</field>
  </row>
</table>
```

Is there any way where i can fetch `"advisory table"` name from xml file and rename my file from media.xml to advisory.xml

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that the `/` at the end of the `<table/>` tag isn't actually there in your real data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping that your `<table>` element isn't actually self-closing, so your XML is valid. If so, you can extract the value of the `name` attribute using a tool such as `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(/table/@name)' media.xml
```

The output of this command is `advisoryTable`. You could pipe the output to sed to remove the `Table` part:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(/table/@name)' media.xml | sed 's/Table//'
```

If you're happy with the result, this could be used within a command substitution to rename your file:

```
mv media.xml "$(xmllint --xpath 'string(/table/@name)' media.xml | sed 's/Table//')"
```

I would be reluctant to encourage automatically renaming files in this way, as you run the risk of accidentally overwriting something. Perhaps it would be a better idea to copy the files instead, possibly using `cp -n` to avoid clobbering files that already exist with the same name.